# Escape key press isn't registered on M1 Macbook

Tags: keyboard, hardware, monterey, siri, apple-silicon

On my 14" M1 MBP running MacOS Monterey, pressing the escape key suddenly stopped registering for exiting dialogs or entering the command mode in VIM. I opened the on-screen keyboard in System Preferences->Accessibility and pressed escape, and it *does* register the keystroke.

Answer (score 2):

After trying a few things and reading around, it turned out that [Siri](https://iboysoft.com/news/escape-key-not-working-mac.html) was somehow to blame. I had also noticed lately that Siri had stopped working, it didn't trigger by voice or clicking the dock icon. After disabling and re-enabling Siri in System Preferences, the escape key immediately started working properly.

Comment: Well done, these sorts of preference settings small corruptions are hard to find. Jiggling the on/off handle is always a great thing to try...

Comment: Wow thank you so much, would never have guessed this! I had just (unsuccessfully) summoned Siri via Fn+Space and afterwards Esc stopped working - but I never would have connected the two events if not for this answer.